Can Button "without an onclick event" be nested inside Link component in NEXT JS
Is it acceptable to integrate a <button> element inside a Next.js <Link> component? I tried this approach, and it didn’t result in a hydration error. Is this a recommended practice, or could it lead to any potential issues?
<Link href={data.buttonUrl}
      target={data.isButtonUrlExternal ? '_blank' : '_self'}
      rel={data.isButtonUrlExternal ? 'noopener' : ''}
>
<button
      data-cy="marketing-box-button"
      className={classNames(
        'text-sm !px-5 max-w-fit uppercase',
        getButtonStyle(buttonStyle)
      )}
      variant="primary"
    >
      {buttonText}
    </button>
</Link>


It's true that it would cause no hydration errors and produce the desired result, but it does not follow the rules of semantic HTML.
Semantic HTML is about using the right element for the right job. Links are for navigation, buttons are for actions like submitting a form or opening a modal.
In the case of accessibility, it may also confuse screen readers.
A <Link> renders an <a> under the hood, which is already interactive, just like a <button>. When you nest them, you’re essentially telling the browser, “Hey! Here’s a clickable thing inside another clickable thing.” which is confusing. Some screen readers might read it out as two separate controls, which isn’t great for accessibility.
While nesting a <button> might seem harmless, writing clean and semantic HTML will make your code more reliable and accessible. It’s a small change, but it makes a big difference!
If you want to make the link look like a button, you can style it that way


<Link
  href={data.buttonUrl}
  target={data.isButtonUrlExternal ? '_blank' : undefined}
  rel={data.isButtonUrlExternal ? 'noopener' : undefined}
  className={classNames(
    'text-sm !px-5 max-w-fit uppercase',
    getButtonStyle(buttonStyle)
  )}
  data-cy="marketing-box-button"
>
  {buttonText}
</Link>



